# Почему не подключаются Google Fonts в WebStorm Live Edit

Tags: шрифты, webstorm, google-fonts

Вот такие ошибки сыпятся,
локальный хостинг через http://localhost:(порт),
В VScode все прекрасно работает, в WebStorm не хочет
[скрин ошибок]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wt3Ft.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте включить опцию **Allow unsigned requests** в **Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger**. По умолчанию при отладке на встроенном веб сервере используется `x-ijt` header для подписки запросов, этот header не посылается, если включена вышеупомянутая опция

Comment: Ответ является решением. Большое спасибо!